# Flutter:Show a snackbar when the app opens either from background or close state

Tags: flutter

I would like to show a snackbar when my app opens from the background or close state. The Snackbar shows up the first time the app open . However, if I place the app in Background and open it again then I don't see the snackbar.

Basically, my App does some task when the user brings the app in the foreground and I want to display a message

Is there a option to display this message when the app comes to the foreground

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override

  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
            
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
       @override
       void initState() {
          super.initState();
       }
                
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return LifeCycleManager(
             child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter Demo',
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                home: Scaffold(
                   body: App(
                        ..
                  ),
                ),
         }
```

----LifeCycleManager.dart

```
class LifeCycleManager extends StatefulWidget {
  LifeCycleManager({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;
  @override
  _LifeCycleManagerState createState() => _LifeCycleManagerState();
}

class _LifeCycleManagerState extends State<LifeCycleManager>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    print('AppLifecycleState: $state');

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
     final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Hi'));
     Future(() => 
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar));
    
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a function when the app is brought to the foreground.

```
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
        super.dispose();
      }


      @override
      void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
          // TRIGGER THE FUNCTION AND SHOW THE SNACKBAR
        }
      }

      @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks . However, not working me .. not seeing the dialog.. I created a LifeCycle widget method and just wrap my main app.. I updated the code..